# builtins.ValueError: 0 is not in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code until now:

```
def alfabeto_deslocado(deslocamento):
letra_inicial = 97 + deslocamento #1a letra deslocada
alfa_lista_deslo = (list(map(chr, range(letra_inicial, 123)))) #lista deslocada até 'z'
alfa_lista_resto = (list(map(chr, range(97, letra_inicial)))) #resto lista desde 'a'
return alfa_lista_deslo + alfa_lista_resto

def encripta_cadeia(cad, chave):
###Encriptar###
cad_chave = repete_chave(cad, chave) #ok
coluna_linha_tab = alfabeto_deslocado(0)
lista_cad = list(cad)
lista_cad_chave = list(cad_chave)
lista_chave = list(chave)
ind_lista_cad_chave = [i for i, valor in enumerate(lista_cad_chave)]
ind_lista_cad = [i for i, valor in enumerate(lista_cad)]
for letra in range(len(cad)):
    indice = alfabeto_deslocado(0).index(letra)
    return indice
```

The code Its not finished , but while testing, the for loop keeps showing the error "builtins.ValueError: 0 is not in list"

```
for letra in range(len(cad)):
    indice = alfabeto_deslocado(0).index(letra)
    return indice
```

Example
(cad, chave) = encripta_cadeia('cantor', 'cima')

alfabeto_deslocado(0)

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: `letra` is an integer, not one of the letters in `cad`. You probably want `for letra in cad:` instead.

Comment: use `print(letra)` to see your problem - you get numbers from `range()`, not chars from `cad`

Comment: @chepner Indeed now it runs, but only returns 1 value, the first value. Its not running all the list.

Comment: you have wrong indentation - `return` is inside `for`-loop - so it exit this loop after first element

Comment: Because `return` causes the function to return immediately; it does not "accumulate" values to be returned once you reach the end of the function.

Comment: @chepner Thanks! I'm understanding now! But can you help me with an example?

Comment: @furas i changed the '''return''', but now gives one value, but the wrong value

Comment: when i replace return, with print, in the same position, it returns all values (2, 0, 13, 19, 14, 17). All correct. but i must not use print

Comment: it seems you don't know how to works with many values - you have to use list. Before loop create empty list, inside loop append value to this list (instead of `print()`), and after loop you will have list with all values - as you expect.

Comment: @furas thanks! Thanks a lot indeed! It Works! And now i know a little more. Small Steps. I'm only a begginer student, freshmen. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `range(len(cad))` gives you numbers (0,1,2...), not chars from `cad`. Yo

```
for letra in cad:
```

---

You have wrong indentation - `return` is inside `for`-loop - so it exit this loop after first element. You have to use `return` after loop.

---

It seems you don't know how to work with many values - you should use list.

Before loop create empty list for all values which you will create in loop.

Inside loop append value to this list (instead of `print()`),

And after loop you will have list with all values - as you expect.

Something like this:

```
# --- before loop ---

results = []

# --- loop --- 

for letra in cad:
    indice = alfabeto_deslocado(0).index(letra)
    results.append(indice)

# --- after loop ---

#print(results)
return results
```